# gradle could not resolve project

Tags: gradle

My project structure is something like.

```
/A
/B/C
/B/D
```

Project `A` depends on `C` and `D` and `D` depends on `C`.
In settings.gradle of project `A` I have declared

```
rootProject.name = 'A'
include ':C', ':D',
project(':C').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../B/C')
project(':D').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../B/D')
```

and in the `build.gradle` of project `A`

```
implementation project(':C')
implementation project(':D')
```

It seems ok for project `C`, while for project `D` I get

```
Could not resolve project :D.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :D:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

Each of the projects have their own settings.gradle file.
Anything I should do in the settings or build file of any of those projects?
Using gradle 6.3 and AdoptOpenJDK 8.0.242

Comment: Are projects `A` and `B` two distinct Gradle projects?